# Volume bounded by the surface $x=-1,\;x=1,\;y=-1,\; y=1, \; z=2,\; y^2+z^2=2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, volume, multiple-integral

> Volume bounded by the surface $x=-1,\;x=1,\;y=-1,\; y=1, \; z=2,\;
> y^2+z^2=2$ in $R^3$

The region $z=2 $ and $y^2+z^2=2$ is confusing me. I know this is a cylinder with axis parallel to $x-axis$ and bounded above and below by $x=1$and $x=-1$ 
 respectively. We take the projection in the $y-z$ plane.

I set up the following integral for this volume :

$$\int_{y=-1}^{1}\int_{z=\sqrt{2-y^2}}^{z=2} \int_{x=-1}^{x=1}dxdzdy$$. Is this correctly set up?

Comment: Try using polar coordinates with $y=\sin(\theta)$, $z=\cos(\theta)$ and $x$.

Comment: My main concern is whether I've set up the integral correctly. The region in the y-z plane is confusing me. I think using polar coordinates will be messy since the limits of y are not $\pm sqrt{2}$. We are not covering the complete circle in the $y-z$ plane

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I have misread the bounds of integration. It seems you have set it up correctly.

Comment: The integral was set up correctly.

Comment: Thank you for confirming